# The member XXX cannot be used as a method or delegate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have done copied this of a tutorial online, but when I compile it shows 2 errors as below:

> Non-invocable member 'Feature.choices' cannot be used like a method

and

> The member `Feature.choices' cannot be used as method or delegate

The last "choices" in the script has a red squiggly line. Any idea that might be wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteInEditMode]

public class FeatureManager : MonoBehaviour {

public List<Feature> features;
public int currFeature;

void OnEnable()
{
    LoadFeatures();
}
void OnDisable()
{
    SaveFeatures();
}
void LoadFeatures()
{
    features = new List<Feature>();
    features.Add(new Feature(("hair"), transform.FindChild("hair").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()));
}
void SaveFeatures()
{

}



}


[System.Serializable]
public class Feature
{
public string ID;
public int currIndex;
public Sprite[] choices;
public SpriteRenderer renderer;

public Feature(string id, SpriteRenderer rend)
{
    ID = id;
    renderer = rend;
    UpdateFeature();
        }

public void UpdateFeature()
{
    choices = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Character/" + ID);

    if (choices == null || renderer == null)
        return;

    if (currIndex < 0)
        currIndex = choices.Length - 1;
    if (currIndex >= choices.Length)
        currIndex = 0;

    renderer.sprite = choices(currIndex);

}



}
```

Comment: I suppose that the error occurs at this line: `renderer.sprite = choices(currIndex)`, which is probably intended to read `renderer.sprite = choices[currIndex]`.

Comment: When you see that, usually it actually just means you have a

simple syntax error.

(Forgotten semicolon, braces instead of brackets, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
renderer.sprite = choices(currIndex);
```

to this:

```
renderer.sprite = choices[currIndex]; // use square brackets not parenthesis
```